# API endpoint to create fallback origin in cloudflare

Tags: cloudflare

Is there an API endpoint to create fallback origin in Cloudflare?

If so, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: Found the API here: https://developers.cloudflare.com/api/operations/custom-hostname-fallback-origin-for-a-zone-update-fallback-origin-for-custom-hostnames